# 'KeyError:' when iterating over pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have two lists `Y_train` and `Y_test`. At the moment they hold categorical data. Each element is either `Blue` or `Green`. They are going to be the targets for a Random Forest classifier. I need them encoded as 1.0s and 0.0s.

Here is a `print(Y_train)` to show you what the data frame looks like. The random numbers down the side are because the data has been shuffled. (`Y_test` is the same, just smaller):

```
183      Blue
126      Blue
1        Blue
409      Blue
575    Green
         ...   
396      Blue
192      Blue
578    Green
838    Green
222      Blue
Name: Colour, Length: 896, dtype: object
```

To encode this I was going to simply loop over them and change each element to their encoded values:

```
for i in range(len(Y_train)):
        if Y_train[i] == 'Blue':
            Y_train[i] = 0.0
        else:
            Y_train[i] = 1.0
```

However, when I do this, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py", line 90, in <module>
    Main()
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py", line 34, in Main
    RandForest(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
  File "G:\Work\Colours.py.py", line 77, in RandForest
    if Y_train[i] == 'Blue':
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1068, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 4730, in get_value
    return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 80, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 88, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 992, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 998, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 6
```

The weird thing is that it produces this error at different times. I've used flags and prints to see how far it gets. Sometimes it will get quite a few iterations into the loop, and then other times it will only do one or two iterations before breaking.

I'm assuming I just don't quite understand how you're supposed to iterate over data frames properly. If someone with more experience with this stuff could help me out that would be great.

Comment: To help people when googling the error in the title: The fundamental misunderstanding is thinking that pandas dataframes are indexed by position the way python lists are, and that therefore a `for` loop over `range(len(thing))` will work for indexing into the dataframe. That's not how dataframes are indexed; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76766374/107331

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 Y_train[Y_train == 'Blue']=0.0
 Y_train[Y_train == 'Green']=1.0
```

That should solve your issues.

Comment: I am having the same issue as the OP, could you explain your solution?

Comment: @PaulCarlson Sure.  `Y_train == 'Blue'` will return a matrix of size of Y_train with boolean type. Wherever Y_train has a value equal to 'Blue', the returned matrix value will be True, and the rest will be False.  Using such a matrix as the index of the Y_train will select only the elements which have the corresponding true boolean value. That's how it works.  I hope it is clear enought?

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you even have more number of labels than your current example(Blue and Green in your case), `sklearn` provides a label encoder that allows you to do this very easily using

```
from sklearn import preprocessing 

label_encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() 

# Transforms the 'column' in your dataframe df
df['column']= label_encoder.fit_transform(df['column'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a your own method to label encoding,it is better to create a separate encoded column rather than modifying original column.After that you can assign encoded column to your dataframe. As a example for your scenario.

```
encoded = np.ones((Y_train.shape[0],1))
for i in range(Y_train.shape[0]):
        if Y_train[i] == 'Blue':
            encoded[i] = 0
```

Note that this will only work for if you have two categories.

for multiple categories,you can use sklearn or pandas methods.

**For multiple categories**

Another approach is using pandas [cat.codes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).You can convert pandas series to a category and get the category codes.

```
Y_train = pd.Series(Y_train)
encoded = Y_train.astype("category").cat.codes
```

You can use [sklearn Labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode categorical data as well.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import  LabelEncoder 
le = LabelEncoder()
encoded = le.fit_transform(Y_train)
```