# KeyError when iterating over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to do a linear regression of a dataset gathering the surfaces and rents of several appartments.

Here is a sample of the dataset displayed in python :
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hiu2U.png)

The form of our model is :

y^=xT.θ
with :  xT=(x1,x2,x3,...,xN),y^T=(y1^,y2^,y3^,...,yN^)

In our case : xTi=(1,vi1) with vi1 = surface of the i-th apartment
Therefore we have : yi^=xTiθ=θ0 + θ1×vi1

Then we define the empirical risk of the model : E=∑Ni=1||xTiθ−yi||2
And we are trying to find the θ that is minimizing E : θ^=argminθE

To do this with Python, the course is using the following code :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


house_data = pd.read_csv('house.csv')

X = np.matrix([np.ones(house_data.shape[0]), house_data['surface'].values]).T

y = np.matrix(house_data['loyer']).T

theta = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)

print(theta)
```

The solution given by the course for X is using np.matrix() but I am trying to have an equivalent of X using np.arrays():

This problem is based on the OpenClassrooms class entitled "Get Started with Machine Learning"
https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4011851-initiez-vous-au-machine-learning/4121986-programmez-votre-premiere-regression-lineaire

To have an equivalent of X I used this lines of code :

```
x = house_data['surface']
for i in range(len(x)):
    A = [1,x[i]]
    X.append(A)
```

I can't explain why but it is working for the 11 first iterations and then it is returning a KeyError : 11

Can someone explain what a KeyError : 11 is and is it possible to have an expression of X using np.array() ?

Here is the entirety of my code :

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd 

house_data = pd.read_csv('house.csv')
house_data = house_data[house_data['loyer']<10000]
x = house_data['surface']
y = house_data['loyer']
X = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    A = [1,x[i]]
    X.append(A)
```

Here is the print(x) : [x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KTYh.png)

Comment: Let's back up a step. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve. It sounds like you are attempting a solution to a problem, but the solution doesn't quite work. So now you are asking how to fix the solution. Instead, we need some more information about the original problem. This is what we call an XY problem.

Comment: The objective is to do a linear regression of the dataset "house.csv". The form of the model is y^=xT.θ Therefore, I have to find the optimal theta that is minimising the empirical risk of the regression. I will edit my initial post to give you all the information.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76766287/edit) your question to include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with test data demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Looks to me like you could just replace the `np.matrix` in your original code with `np.array`. Why are you trying to write a loop?

Comment: Looking at the edit, you'd need to adjust the construction of `y`. `np.array` won't force things to be 2-dimensional. You'd have to add the extra dimension manually.

Comment: Using something like np.reshape() ? or not at all ?

Comment: `np.reshape` would work, or indexing with `None` to add a length-1 dimension in the `None`'s position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one solution to your issue is to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd 

house_data = pd.read_csv('house.csv')
x = house_data['surface']
y = house_data['loyer']
X = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    A = [1,x[i]]
    if y[i] < 10000:
        X.append(A)
```

That, however, doesn't answer your question: why are you getting `KeyError`?

The answer is that pandas dataframes aren't indexed by *position*, they're indexed by the dataframe's *index* column. By default, a dataframe's index column starts out the same as position, but by doing things like you do with the line

```
house_data = house_data[house_data['loyer']<10000]
```

you can end up eliminating rows of the dataframe and therefore dropping index values. To see what's going on, consider this example:

```
>>> small_house_data = pd.DataFrame(data={'surface': [37, 52, 42], 'loyer': [8888, 11111, 7777]})
>>> small_house_data
   surface  loyer
0       37   8888
1       52  11111
2       42   7777
>>> small_house_data2 = small_house_data[small_house_data['loyer'] < 10000]
>>> small_house_data2
   surface  loyer
0       37   8888
2       42   7777
>>> len(small_house_data2)
2
>>> small_house_data2[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
   .... lots of lines of ugly traceback omitted ....
KeyError: 1
```

I got a `KeyError` there because `small_house_data2` doesn't have anything for index value `1`.

There are two basic ways around this: reset the index on your `house_data` dataframe after you select out the spots with `loyer` less than `10000`, or in your `for` loop iterate over the dataframe's actual index instead of the range.

That is:

```
house_data = pd.read_csv('house.csv')
house_data = house_data[house_data['loyer']<10000]
x = house_data['surface']
y = house_data['loyer']
X = []

for i in x.index:
    A = [1,x[i]]
    X.append(A)
```

or

```
house_data = pd.read_csv('house.csv')
house_data = house_data[house_data['loyer']<10000]
house_data = house_data.reset_index(drop=True)
x = house_data['surface']
y = house_data['loyer']
X = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    A = [1,x[i]]
    X.append(A)
```